# Google Chrome display corrupted over VNC

Tags: macos, google-chrome, remote-desktop

Over VNC, everything looks great *except* Google Chrome, which is completely messed up (image below). Chrome is fine if I'm using the machine directly instead.

This is a brand-new Mac Mini (Yosemite 10.10.5), literally *just* set it up and enabled VNC access. It's done one OS update and reboot.

How can I fix it?

Here's the screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Turning off hardware acceleration in Chrome fixes it:

1. Connect directly (so you can see Chrome)
2. Go into Chrome's Settings
3. Scroll down and choose "Advanced settings"
4. Scroll right down and eventually you'll see **Use hardware acceleration when available** — turn it off, restart Chrome, and you're all set

[image]